# Firebase console user admin functions for profiles

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Is there a way to view/edit users profile data from the firebase console itself? I only need to change one or two things and don't want to build out a whole wrapper for the Admin SDK for such a small task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using the Firebase console.  You will have to write code to make changes, or find some other utility to do this.

Comment: The simplest way to do this in code is with the Admin SDK, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user